# Simple search programme does not return results c#

Tags: c#, winforms, search, for-loop

I am trying to do a simple search program that allows the user to search for an employee's name and click on the search button which will return the employee details.

In my Form I have:

```
    private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set datasource
        dataGridView1.DataSource = controller_emp.search_employee(textBoxSearch.Text);
    }
```

Controller_Employee:

```
    public Model_Employee search_employee(string criteria)
    {
        return db.search_employee(criteria);
    }
```

Model_DB_Employee:

```
    public Model_Employee search_employee(string criteria)
    {

        Model_Employee result = new Model_Employee();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((string)empTab.Rows[i]["emp_fname"] == criteria)
            {
                result.setId(empTab.Rows[i]["emp_id"].ToString());
                result.setFname(empTab.Rows[i]["emp_fname"].ToString());
                result.setLname(empTab.Rows[i]["emp_lname"].ToString());
                result.setUsername(empTab.Rows[i]["username"].ToString());
                result.setPassword(empTab.Rows[i]["passwd"].ToString());
                result.setJobrole(empTab.Rows[i]["job_role"].ToString());
                result.setContact(empTab.Rows[i]["contact"].ToString());
                result.setEmail(empTab.Rows[i]["email"].ToString());
            }

        }
        return result;

    }
```

Is there anything wrong with the `for` loop? It keeps on looping even when the `criteria` has been met.

Comment: Well, of course it keeps looping after `criteria` has been met. That's what the code has been written to do. By the way, why aren't you doing the filtering on `criteria` in the database?

Comment: `if(empTab.Select("emp_fname like '%'").Equals(criteria))`
                
Do you mean like this? Sorry I just started on programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break;`

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
{
    if ((string)empTab.Rows[i]["emp_fname"] == criteria)
    {
        //result stuff
        break;
    }
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not exit the loop when you found the employee.
You can:
1. Use `break` immediately after populating the result with the information
2. copy the `return result;` immediately after populating the result with the information

I like best option number 1 :)